# .attr() doesn't work with select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, combobox

I have problem with .attr method
I want to change the class of every select box that I added

for more details [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eldepe18/fDzNz/6/)

Anything wrong with it..?

Comment: Please specify your problem i didnt find any prob in the code

Comment: the class attribute of the select box doesn't change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand well what you have to do, this is the trouble.

```
//c.children(':text').attr('class','jabatan'+ (++i) );
c.children('select').addClass('jabatan' + (++i));
```

I think your selector (that I commented) don't find anything, and so don't add anything

I hope it helps

Comment: how if i want to set the value of the select box
Can I use .val() method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `removeClass` and `addClass` instead of just `attr`? Alternatively, have you tried getting a direct reference to the node and setting className (`$(somenode)[0].className = "somevalue"`)?